Why is my GPU not being used despite having turned it on in Kaggle?
I've uploaded a dataset on kaggle(approx. 73GB), and I'm trying to preprocess this data for model training purposes. This dataset has a large no. of missing values, which I am trying to interpolate for data preparation. I'm currently running the following piece of code to interpolate the data:
import xarray as xr
import dask

# Ensuring Dask's distributed scheduler is set up
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()

# Loading the combined SST dataset
dataset_path = '/kaggle/input/combined-sst-data/combined_sst_data.nc'
ds = xr.open_dataset(dataset_path, engine='h5netcdf', chunks={'time': 'auto'})

# # Rechunk the dataset so the 'time' dimension is in a single chunk
# ds_rechunked = ds.chunk({'time': -1})

# # Now, try to interpolate missing values across the 'time' dimension
# sst_filled = ds_rechunked['sea_surface_temperature'].interpolate_na(dim='time', method='linear')

# # Since operations with Dask are lazy, trigger computation to evaluate results
# sst_filled = sst_filled.compute()

# # Example to save output data - Kaggle allows you to write files
# sst_filled.to_netcdf('cleaned_sst_data.nc')

ds_grouped = ds.groupby('time').mean()

# Ensure all operations are completed if using Dask
ds_grouped = ds_grouped.compute()

However, Kaggle ends up using CPU instead of GPU for this. In the following image you can see how CPU is being used despite the GPU accelerator being on. This leads to the kernel dying before the process completes.

I've tried looking for solutions, for example this thread has people encountering the same problem but no helpful solutions yet.
I came across this stackoverflow question where it is suggested to use CPU instead of GpU which made me wonder if there is a problem with my approach and that is why the GPU was not being used, however the content is from 2017 and I'm not sure if it is outdated at this time.
I'm relatively new to this field and do not have a clear understanding of these concepts yet, so any help would be appreciated!

Have you tried a PyTorch GPU operation to make sure that it's not your GPU, but instead xarray's access to your GPU?
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") then print(device)

I tried executing this piece of code to which the output was "cuda", which I'm guessing implies that the gpu is available. However, I don't understand how to proceed after this.

I don't think xarray is GPU accelerated by default. You could check out this project that's a GPU accelerated version of xarray. You can install it with pip install cupy-xarray.
Usage example:
import xarray as xr
import cupy_xarray  # This registers the `DataSet.cupy` and `DataArray.cupy` namespaces but is not used directly

ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature.nc")
type(ds.air.data)  # numpy.ndarray

%timeit ds.air.mean()  # 8.56 ms ± 15.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

ds = ds.cupy.as_cupy()  # Also available via convenience method ds.as_cupy()
type(ds.air.data)  # cupy.core.core.ndarray

%timeit ds.air.mean()  # 2.14 ms ± 21.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

ds = ds.as_numpy()
type(ds.air.data)  # numpy.ndarray

From what I gather, it seems like you can just import cupy_xarray after your import xarray as xr and it will work.

This is a great suggestion and would have worked, however cupy-xarray no longer supports macOS. Here is the output for pip install cupy-xarray after trying it in my terminal:
`Error: macOS is no longer supported.
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.`

@54m4gr4 That's a bummer, I hope you end up finding a workaround. I don't know anything about Macs, I haven't used one since iMacs looked like CRT monitors. Best of luck.
